# Can a to infinitive and a gerund both be an object of the verb teach?

Tags: gerunds, bare-infinitives, direct-objects

*To* infinitive and gerund can be an object of the verb teach?

I wonder if these sentences are grammatically correct or incorrect and reasons.

1) I teach you to speak English.

2) I teach you speaking English.

3) I teach to speak English to you.

4) I teach speaking English to you.

I really wonder please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For what I assume is the intended sense, OP's example #1 is the most natural alternative:

> 1) I teach you [**how**] to speak English

But the second version *doesn't* have that meaning:

> 2) I teach you speaking English.

In principle that *could* make sense if we interpret it as meaning *I speak in English while teaching you [something, not necessarily how **you** should speak English]*. Or at a stretch we could interpret "speaking English" as a noun phrase equivalent to "**spoken** English", but that's a rather non-standard usage.

Example #3 is simply ungrammatical. There's not much more to say about it.

Example #4 is syntactically "valid", but if the teacher was any good at his job that's probably not how he would phrase it. He'd probably use the format of example #1 anyway, but if he wanted to focus on the actual *subject* (the spoken language), as opposed to the *goal* (that you learn to speak English), he's more likely say:

> 5) I teach you spoken English

(Note that this version more strongly implies I *only* teach spoken English, not the written form.)

Answer (score 0):

**You teach someone to do something**.

**He is teaching you to speak English**.

to here refers to a purpose, a reason.

If you teach something, you can say:

I teach English.
I teach sailing. [the activity of sailing a boat]
I am teaching them to speak English.

However, we would not say: I am teaching speaking **unless** it refers to public speaking, the activity.

I teach public speaking to business people.

The ing forms in your example refer to the activity of teaching, and there we just use the nouns: I teach math or I teach Chinese.

If you want to say to teach someone spoken as opposed to written English, you can say:

I teach **English conversation classes**.